# Objective C: Programmatically create a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, button, uiimageview

I'm trying to make a UIImageView with a .png load up in the location of a button when it is clicked.

```
brickAnim = UIImageView.alloc;           ///////freezes during runtime
[brickAnim initWithFrame:currentBrick.frame];
[brickAnim setImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"brick-1.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:brickAnim];
```

`current brick` is the name of the button that's being clicked. I've narrowed it down and figured out that the first line causes the app to freeze and exit. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
brickAnim = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brick-1.png"]];
brickAnim.frame = currentBrick.frame;
[self.view addSubview:brickAnim];
```

edit after seeing response to other answer:

are you declaring and initializing brickAnim elsewhere? if not, you need to add at the beginning:

```
UIImageView *brickAnim = [[UIImageView alloc] ....;
```

and at the end:

```
[brickAnim release];
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a UIImage first, since setImage wants an UIImage object. Something like this may work (note that this is a class method):

```
[brickAnim setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brick-1.png"]];
```

Look at the UIImage reference, i'm not sure this will work (since imageNamed may want a different path-format).