# How to display image in iphone simulator using objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to display image in iphone simulator programmatically using objective c, I am using following code, but it is not displaying anything in simulator

```
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage *myimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A1.jpg"];
imageview.image=myimg;
```

Comment: You are doing this right. My guess is that you messed up the UIImageView and how you added that to your UIViewController. Show us how you've done that.

Comment: Where i need to put my image to display it?

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/23/tutorial-all-about-images-part-1-uimage-uiimageview/ That should help you finding out how to create an UIImageView to your UIViewController with the appropriate image you want. Remember to add the file to your project!

Comment: use this  [self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"A1.png"]]];

NOTE: use png format image

Comment: `colorWithPatternImage:` draws image like a repeating texture, that's not a case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C: Programmatically create a UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671253/objective-c-programmatically-create-a-uiimageview)

Comment: And duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891613/create-uiimageview/7891670#7891670

Anyhow there are lots of examples and tutorials on how to use a UIImageView with an image.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this code

```
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage *myimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A1.jpg"];
imageview.image=myimg;
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150); // pass your frame here
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot this:

```
imageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are programmatically creating the imageView then you must  add it to the view heirarchy using below line

```
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your image view into view like this

```
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithframe:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
UIImage *myimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A1.jpg"];
imageview.image=myimg;
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

Comment: Where i need to save the image in iphone simulator, to display it?

Comment: you can save image A1.jpg in your resource folder by simply dragging image from your system to xcode project. make sure you check copy item into destination group's folder

Answer (score 1):

First you need to initialize your UIImageView and assign UIImage to it's image property. You already did it in your code. Then you can set the frame to image view.

```
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 150);
```

But in most cases it will be more useful to pass sizeToFit message to your image view.

```
[imageview sizeToFit];
```

So it will change it's frame to fit image's size. But using this approach you need to assign the origin to your image view's frame later. So the best solution is assign the frame in initialization and then pass sizeToFit.

```
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
UIImage *myimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A1.jpg"];
imageview.image=myimg;
[imageview sizeToFit];
```

And don't forget to add image view to view hierarchy.

```
[self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

Also you need to check if your image is correctly added to your project. You can check it by finding you image file in Project Navigator and checking it's Target Membership in File Inspector. There should be a tick beside you target's name.